# DELETE return ERROR 405(Method Not allowed) I'm using React and ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, plesk

I am attempting to delete a row by using the id on the row. when I Execute it on Local server, it worked correctly,but on plesk server have an error.
Requests CREATE and GET worked correctly but for DELETE and UPDATE not work.

> function DELETE:

```
onDeleteConfirmation(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;

    axios.delete("api/Trips/DeleteTrip/" + id).then(result => {
        this.props.history.push('/Trips')
    });
}
```

> funtion UPDATE:

```
onUpdateConfirmation(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    let tripObject = {
        name: this.state.name,
        description: this.state.description,
        dateStarted: this.state.dateStarted,
        dateComplated: this.state.dateComplated
    }
    axios.put("api/Trips/UpdateTrip/"+id, tripObject).then(result => {
        this.props.history.push('/Trips')
    });
}
```

> Controller Service:

```
[HttpDelete("DeleteTrip/{id}")]
    public IActionResult DeleteTrip(int id)
    {
        _service.DeleteTrip(id);
        return Ok();
    }
```

[image]
.
I use ASP.Net Core 3 and React in visual stdio.
my proble accure when I try to execute at online server Plesk.

> This is Full controller:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Trips.Data.Models;
    using Trips.Data.Services;

namespace Trips.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TripsController : ControllerBase
    {
        public ITripService _service { get; set; }

        public TripsController(ITripService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        [EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]
        [HttpGet("GetTrips")]
        public IActionResult GetTrips()
        {
            try
            {
                //throw new Exception();
                var allTrips = _service.GetAllTrips();
                return Ok(allTrips);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        [EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]
        [HttpGet("SingleTrip/{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetTripById(int id)
        {
            var trip = _service.GetTripById(id);
            return Ok(trip);
        }

        [EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]
        [HttpPost("AddTrip")]
        public IActionResult AddTrip([FromBody] Trip trip)
        {
            if (trip != null)
            {
                _service.AddTrip(trip);
            }
            return Ok();
        }

        [EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]
        [HttpPut("UpdateTrip/{id}")]
        public IActionResult UpdateTrip(int id, [FromBody] Trip trip)
        {
            _service.UpdateTrip(id, trip);
            return Ok(trip);
        }

        [EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]
        [HttpDelete("DeleteTrip/{id}")]
        public IActionResult DeleteTrip(int id)
        {
            _service.DeleteTrip(id);
            return Ok();
        }

    }
}
```

.

> StartUp.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });

            // 
            services.AddTransient<ITripService, TripService>();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AnotherPolicy",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins(
                                "http://hirkansolar.ir/",
                                "http://react.hirkansolar.ir/"
            )
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "POST");
                    });
            });

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            // ----
            app.UseCors();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I see full controller?

Comment: I added the full controller.

Comment: Hi, if you are using shared hosting, then that is the problem

Answer (score 3):

According to Plesk, This is because **WebDAV and .NET Core IIS handlers conflict** and advised to **Disable WebDAV module and its headers from the website configuration**.

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008566053-HTTP-Error-405-Method-Not-Allowed-when-using-PUT-method-in-ASP-NET-or-NET-Core-application-with-Web-API

Add the following code to your web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules>
      <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
   </modules>

   <handlers>
      <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
      <remove name="WebDAV" />

      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
   </handlers>
    
   other configs here...
    
</system.webServer>
```

You might have to this each time before you upload the application files to Plesk panel.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add CORS headers in responses to enable DELETE requests across origins.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0

In your `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options => { // <--- define a policy
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => {
            builder.WithOrigins(
                "http://example.com",
                "http://www.contoso.com"
            )
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });
    // ...
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // ...
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors(); // <--- enable the middleware

    // ...
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
}
```

After you make this change, responses should include `Access-Control-Allow-...` headers.

Comment: I use `UseCores()` but not worked and didn't Allow to use the Update and Delete.
I changed `StartUp.cs` and add two section.

Comment: Can you post your Startup.cs?

Comment: Your problem is most certainly caused by a CORS issue. It needs to be set up correctly to function.

Comment: @abdusco The issue is the configuration on plesk. PUT, PATCH, DELETE doesn't work with most shared hosting that using plesk.

Comment: @IkelieCyril Huh. Are they really changing the response headers?

Comment: @abdusco So, according to Plesk, this is because WebDAV and .NET Core IIS handlers conflict and Plesk advised to disable WebDAV module and its headers from the website configuration. I posted an answer